# Naming variables with utf characters

Tags: c#

What determines what utf characters can be used in code?

```
var süßigkeit = new Candy(); // works
var süßigkeit∆ = süßigkeit + 1; // doesn't work
```

Comment: The compiler you use, but the text editor is first.  Chicken-and-egg, the egg won't give you a hard time.  Avoid Notepad, like editors that emit da BOM for utf-8 encoded text files.  Like VS does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from Microsoft docs:

> - Identifiers must start with a letter, or `_`.
> - Identifiers may contain Unicode letter characters, decimal digit characters, Unicode
>     connecting characters, Unicode combining characters, or Unicode
>     formatting characters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/identifier-names

```
Char.GetUnicodeCategory('∆') // MathSymbol category
```